# HTML Link and Jquery Live Only Works on First Try with one click

Tags: javascript, live, jquery

I'm running into a problem with jquery live event binding on a link.  When the link is added to the page it works fine, however when another link is added to the unordered list it requires two clicks for the click event to fire on either link.  Any ideas?

```
$("div#website-messages ul li a").live("click", function() {
    var link = $(this);
    changeTab(link.attr("href"));
    $(link.attr("title")).focus();
    return false;
});
```

EDIT:  OK I've narrowed down the problem.  If I take out return false, the event fires every time.  The problem is then the page jumps to the top.  Any ideas to stop that?

Code that creates the links:

```
Validation.validate = function() {
    var html = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
        html += "<li><a href='" + errors[i].tabid + "' title='" + errors[i].elementID + "'>" + errors[i].message + "</a></li>";
    }
    $("div#website-messages ul").html(html);
}
```

ChangeTab Function

```
function changeTab(changeTo) {
    changeTo = changeTo.substr(changeTo.indexOf("#"), changeTo.length);
    $("#tabs div").hide();
    $(changeTo).show();

    $("ul.navigation li a").removeClass("selected");
    $("ul.navigation li a[href='" + changeTo + "']").addClass("selected");
}
```

**SOLVED**
I had a blur event on the text inputs that were being focused to that validated them.  If I clicked on one of the errors and focused to the first textbox, then clicked on the second error, it would focus to the second textbox but fire the blur event and not focus.  Thank you all SO much for your help and suggestions, this was driving me crazy all day.

Comment: Does the code run twice, once for each link? Try putting an alert inside the function ...

Comment: Yes, the code will run once for each link.  Then after that it requires a double click to get it to run.

Comment: @Jon I think what James was suggesting was that by clicking a single link just once, the code you have there may in fact be executing twice.  And as a result gets into a strange state where the behavior is getting unexpected results because each click executes the code multiple times.  Can you provide an example of  your problem on jsbin.com?

Comment: I'm trying to create a sample on jsbin and it won't reproduce the problem.

Comment: I would suggest trying to narrow down the differences between your code and what is working in jsbin - obviously something is different

Comment: The reason the page jumps to the top is that the browser is reloading the page. That's why you need to prevent the browser from processing the link (using `return false`, `event.preventDefault`, `void(0)`, etc). What I'm wondering is What are you trying to do when you add `.focus()` on the link? I posted a demo here on how focus works/doesn't work (http://pastebin.me/973509bd873d9ef90fa19c961e77fb27). And as said before an example on jsbin would be much more helpful. What are you trying to accomplish with changing tabs and link locations?

Comment: I'm not trying to focus to the link.  The title attribute of the link has the ID of the text input I am trying to focus to.

Comment: @Jon, in that case, $(link.attr("title")).focus(); should actually be $('#' + link.attr("title")).focus(); since it is an element id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a blur event on the text inputs that were being focused to that validated them. If I clicked on one of the errors and focused to the first textbox, then clicked on the second error, it would focus to the second textbox but fire the blur event and not focus.

Answer (score 1):

> EDIT: OK I've narrowed down the
>   problem. If I take out return false,
>   the event fires every time. The
>   problem is then the page jumps to the
>   top. Any ideas to stop that?

try

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: That brings back the same problem I had before. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Since it jumps to the top ... what is the content of the actual href?  If it is something like "#", then it will likely jump to the top.  If the result of the click is to change the content on the page, instead of actually navigating away from the page, you might consider using:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">linky</a>
```

Comment: This stops the page from jumping to the top but also stops the event from firing every time.

Comment: I guess I'm confused as to what you are trying to accomplish - does the link navigate to a new page or not? If you're just using the link to trigger events on the page, then you have to return false or use javascript:void(0), or # as the href.  If you don't return false, it will navigate to the url of the href.

Answer (score 1):

this prevent link jumps to the top:

```
<div id="website-messages">
<ul>
<li><a href="javascript:;" >my link</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

this make js it fire every time!

```
$("div#website-messages ul li a").live("click", function(e) {
    //this make it fire every time!
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this);
    changeTab(link.attr("href"));
    $(link.attr("title")).focus();
});
```

**UPDATE:**

your link should be something like this:

```
<li><a id='" + errors[i].elementID + "' href='javascript:;' title='" + errors[i].tabid + "'>" + errors[i].message + "</a></li>
```

Comment: Same problem :-( .  Any other suggestions?

Comment: I have a form that has a tabbed interface.  On the right hand side I list all of the errors for the form and each error is clickable.  When the user clicks the error, it changes to the correct tab and should focus to the text input associated with the error.  Do you know of another way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: maybe the problem is elsewhere, the correct form of prevent link jump on top is or using return false; or preventDefault; can you add some other code!?

Comment: Nevermind my last comment on focus(); my bad; check instead the changeTab(link.attr("href")); is probably the tabs that causing the mistake! make a try!

Comment: Still not working, I added the changeTab function to the code above.  Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: OK, I've narrowed it down even further.  If I am on any other tab and click any of the error links it works perfectly.  The only time it does not work is when I am in the same tab as the as the tab the error link is taking me to.